# Vue call method of another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two component a Card component and a modal component, the modal component contains the modal Elements, in my Card component I would like to have a button which opens the modal Window of my modal component. How do I manage that, so far I have done this:

My Card component:

```
<template>
    <v-layout v-if="visible">
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title primary-title>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="headline mb-0">test</h3>
                        <div>test</div>
                    </div>
                </v-card-title>

                <v-divider light></v-divider>

                <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn
                    color="primary"
                    dark
                    @click="dialog = true"
                >
                Open Dialog
                </v-btn> <!-- open modal dialog of modal component? -->

                    <tenant-number-modal></tenant-number-modal>
                </v-card-actions>

                <input type="hidden" id="tenant-id" :value=tenantId>
            </v-card>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                visible: true,
                dialog: false,
                uniqueTenantNumber: ''
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

My Modal component:

```
<template>
    <v-layout row justify-center>
        <v-btn
            color="primary"
            dark
            @click="dialog = true"
        > <!-- this calls the modal but only in this component -->
        Open Dialog
        </v-btn>

        <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            max-width="290"
        >
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="headline">test</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        dialog: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call a method of another component by using a `ref`.

```
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
       color="primary"
       dark
       @click="openModal">
      Open Dialog
      </v-btn> <!-- open modal dialog of modal component? -->
      <tenant-number-modal ref="modal"></tenant-number-modal>
    </v-card-actions>
...
<script>
   export default {
      data () {
         return {
            //visible: true,
            //dialog: false,
            //uniqueTenantNumber: ''
         }
      },
      methods: {
         openModal() {
            this.$refs.modal.showModal();
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Your modal component:

```
<template>
    <v-layout row justify-center>
    ...
        <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            max-width="290">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="headline">test</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        dialog: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
       showModal() {
       this.dialog = true;
       }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice this worked but there is no modal fade in Animation, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is create an event bus. This will allow you to send messages to 1+ components at once. Once you emit the message, then all components that are listening will execute.

First you need to create the bus:

**bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Next in the component that will emit the message you call `EventBus.$emit(name, data)`

**componentA.js**

```
import { EventBus } from './bus.js';

export default {
  methods: {
    emitGlobalClickEvent() {
      EventBus.$emit('i-got-clicked', 'extra data');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your other components, you just need to listen for the event. The following can be added to the component and you just need to use `EventBus.$on(name, handle)` or if you only want to listen once use `EventBus.$once(name, handle)`.

**componentB.js**

```
import { EventBus } from './bus.js';

export default {
  created() {
    EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', data => {
      console.log(data)
      // You can then call your method attached to this component here
      this.openModal()
    });
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      console.log('I am opening')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Was stuck on this for 3 days, finally! Only this works for independent components.

Comment: @HariHarker I would now recommend using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

For call any method of a component from any other component

Add a `$on` function to the `$root` instance from mounted section. then call form any other component accessing the `$root` and calling `$emit` function.

On first component:

```
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('mySpecialName', () => {
            // your code goes here
        }
    }
```

on second component:

```
    someComponent2Method: function(){
     // your code here
     this.$root.$emit('mySpecialName') //like this
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

TestModal.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="modalState" max-width="500px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        This is a modal in another component.
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="modalState = false">
          Close
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      modalState: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.modalState = true
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

in your parent file (index.vue):

```
<template>
  <v-layout column justify-center align-center>
    <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
      <test-modal ref="customModal" />
      <v-btn large color="primary" @click.stop="runModal">
        Run Modal
      </v-btn>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import TestModal from '~/components/TestModal.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    TestModal,
  },
  methods: {
    runModal() {
      this.$refs.customModal.showModal()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```